# In Python 2.7. how do I Read in Specific Text From a File and Assign to Variable

Tags: variables, text, save, assign

How do I read in text as string instead of an integer?

```
latstart = content.find("Latitude=")
latend = content.find("Latitude=",latstart+1)
longstart = content.find("Longitude=",start)
longend = content.find(",",longstart)
```

These lines are supposed to read in data as text, but all I get are these numbers (respectively)...

```
5639
-1
5664
8795
```

The raw data from file...

```
[SimVars.0]
Latitude=N21° 20' 47.36"
Longitude=W157° 27' 23.20"
```

What is wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do what I believe you're trying for in your question:

```py
content='''
[SimVars.0]
Latitude=N21° 20' 47.36"
Longitude=W157° 27' 23.20"
'''

latKey = "Latitude="
longKey = "Longitude="

try:
    latstart = content.index(latKey) + len(latKey)
    latend = content.find('"', latstart) + 1
    longstart = content.find(longKey, latend) + len(longKey)
    longend = content.find('"', longstart) + 1
except (ValueError):
    print("couldn't find latitude and longitude")

print(f'latstart {latstart}')
print(f'latend {latend}')
print(f'longstart {longstart}')
print(f'longend {longend}')

lat = content[latstart:latend]
long = content[longstart:longend]

print()
print(f'lat {lat}')
print(f'long {long}')
```

Output:

```
latstart 22
latend 37
longstart 48
longend 64

lat N21° 20' 47.36"
long W157° 27' 23.20"
```

---

**Comments on you question:**

The [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method of python's built-in [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) data type returns the position of the first argument if found, and -1 if not found. To get text, you will need to do something like `lat = content[latstart:latend]` after using `find()` to set `latstart` and `latend`.

The [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) method of `str` is an alternative to `find()` which in a success scenario does the same thing, but in a failure scenario will raise a `ValueError` exception (instead of returning -1). If you catch this exception using a `try/catch` block as in the code above, it saves you the trouble of checking the return values of individual calls to `find()` for -1, and takes some of the guesswork out of debugging your code.

**UPDATE**:

In response to OP's comment that `print()` is throwing an exception, given that you are using python version 2.7, let me simplify the code to see if we can get you something that works in your environment:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
content='''
[SimVars.0]
Latitude=N21° 20' 47.36"
Longitude=W157° 27' 23.20"
'''

latKey = "Latitude="
longKey = "Longitude="

latstart = content.index(latKey) + len(latKey)
latend = content.find('"', latstart) + 1
longstart = content.find(longKey, latend) + len(longKey)
longend = content.find('"', longstart) + 1

print('latstart ', latstart)
print('latend ', latend)
print('longstart ', longstart)
print('longend ', longend)

lat = content[latstart:latend]
long = content[longstart:longend]

print()
print('lat ', lat)
print('long ', long)
```

Output:

```
latstart  22
latend  37
longstart  48
longend  64

lat  N21° 20' 47.36"
long  W157° 27' 23.20"
```

Comment: Thank you again. I admit I don't fully understand, but this gives me a direction to try and research. I have been working on this for three days. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first "print" line in the first "print" block -->>print(f'latstart {latstart}')<<-- is throwing a syntax error. I can't figure out why?

Comment: It appears to be related to the "try" statement block above it. Just guessing.

Comment: For clarity, the goal my script is to read in the text...

lat N21° 20' 47.36"
long W157° 27' 23.20" 

...from a text file and convert to Decimal Degrees...

lat N21.34649
long W157.4564

I hope this makes sense?

Comment: @Calvin The goal you expressed in your comment is different from what you asked in this question. However, I note that you have another question outstanding that asks for the full conversion. Let's deal with this question first, then (if you still need it) I'll try to answer your other question separately.

Comment: OK, please see the update within my answer. This should work for python version 2.7.